# stack memory allocation

Tags: multithreading, memory, memory-management, stack

I had a debate with friend who said that in C, the memory is allocated in compile time.
I said it cannot be true since memory can be allocated only when the process loads to memory.
From this to that we started talking about stack allocation, after reading, I know its OS implementation,
But usually the stack start in default size, 1 MB (sequential) lets say, of reserved Virtual address, and when the function is called (no matter where we are on the stack of that thread),
A block of bytes in size X (all local variable for that function?) is commited (allocated) from the reserved address.

What I would like to understand, When we enter the function, How does the OS knows how big is the size to allocate (commit from reserved)?
Does it happen dynamically during the function execution ? or the compiler knows to calculate before each function what size this function needs ?

Comment: this- the compiler knows to calculate before each function what size this function needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler can and does (at compile time) count up the sizes of all the local variables that the function declares on the stack, and thereby it knows (again, at compile time) how much it will need to increase the stack-pointer when the function is entered (and decrease it when the function returns).  This computed amount-to-increase-the-stack-pointer-by value will be written into the executable code directly at compile time, so that it doesn't need to be re-computed when the function is called at run time.

The exception to the above is when your C program is using C99s's [variable-length-arrays (VLA) feature](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/).  As suggested by the name, variable-length-arrays are arrays whose size is not known until run-time, and as such the compiler will have to emit special code for any function that contains one or more VLAs, such that the amount by which to increase the stack-pointer is calculated at run-time.

Note that the physical act of mapping virtual stack addresses to physical RAM addresses (and making sure that the necessary RAM is allocated) is done at run time, and is handled by the operating system, not by the compiler.  In particular, if a process tries to access a virtual address (on the stack or otherwise) that is not currently mapped to any physical address, a [page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) will be generated by the MMU.  The process's executation will be temporarily paused while a page-fault-handler routine executes.  The page-fault-handler will evaluate the legality of the virtual address the process tried to access; if the virtual address was a legal one, the page-fault-handler will map it to an appropriate page of physical RAM, and then let the process continue executing.  If the virtual address was not one the process is allowed to access (or if the attempt to procure a page of physical RAM failed, e.g. because the computer's memory is full), then the mapping will fail and the OS will halt/crash the process.